# OrderedDictionary value not returning list but object

Tags: c#, dictionary, ordereddictionary

Ok, I give up. It's probably something really simple I'm missing but I've been stuck on this for the last 2 hours and I can't find the answer anywhere online. The below code shows a CS1579 error in my `list` inside my `foreach` saying that:

> "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'".

Shouldn't my `roomList[roomNameTest]` return a `List<string>`?

```
var roomList = new OrderedDictionary();

var listA = new List<string>();
listA.Add("elemA");
listA.Add("elemB");

roomList["roomA"] = listA;

var roomNameTest = "roomA";

if (roomList.Contains(roomNameTest))
{
    var list = roomList[roomNameTest];

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Using a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>()` worked really well and I used the `OrderBy(x => x.Key)` to sort the dictionary later on as I needed. Thanks everybody for the contribution, much appreciated.

Comment: `OrderedDictionary` isn't a generic class so it works with `object`s only. You will need to cast or use a different type of collection. Do you really need it to be ordered?

Comment: No, if `roomList["roomA"]` is an `object`.

Comment: `var list = (List<string>)roomList[roomNameTest];` will fix it (in this very case)

Comment: why does your collection has to be ordered if you want to use a dictionary?

Comment: If you use `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` instead and then `roomList.ContainsKey`, this code will work fine. I'd be surprised if you really need to stick with `OrderedDictionary`

Comment: First of all, I wanted to say I really appreciate everyone's contribution. It's great to see I went to bed last night with a problem and woke up to several solutions.  :-)
The reason why I went for OrderedDictionary is because the plan was to sort it by key after populating it but I'm starting to see that the OrderedDictionary only records the order with which everything was added to it and there doesn't seem to be any functionality to sort it later on.

Comment: I'll try all your suggestions later today and report back, thanks everyone.

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` isn't ordered, which given that you started with `OrderedDictionary` seems likely to be a criteria. See duplicate for information about generic options that provide ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderedDictionary` isn't a generic class so it works with `object`s only. You will need to cast or use a different type of collection. For example:

```
var list = (List<string>) roomList[roomNameTest];
```

But that might lead to issues if you add something that is not a `<List<string>` to the dictionary.

Also, I'm not really sure that you need to use `OrderedDictionary` here, and a strongly typed `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` would be much better. For example:

```
var roomList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

//...

if (roomList.ContainsKey(roomNameTest))
{
    //...
}
```

Though I would also recommend using `TryGetValue`:

```
if(roomList.TryGetValue(roomNameTest, out var list))
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, since items of `OrderedDictionary` declared being of type `object`, .Net treats them as
instances of `object`, which don't imeplement `IEnumerable`. For instance you can easily put

```
  roomList.Add("abc", 123);
  roomList.Add("def", true);
  roomList.Add("pqr", "bla-bla-bla");
```

You can try casting these items
into `IEnumerable<string>` and on success looping:

```
  var roomList = new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary();

  var listA = new List<string>();
  listA.Add("elemA");
  listA.Add("elemB");

  // Note "Add", since item with Key == "roomA" doesn't exist
  roomList.Add("roomA", listA);

  var roomNameTest = "roomA";

  if (roomList.Contains(roomNameTest)) {
    // if item implements IEnumerable<string>, say it List<string>
    // we can loop over it  
    if (roomList[roomNameTest] is IEnumerable<string> list)
      foreach (var item in list) {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I just had a better look at your answer and I definitely appreciate that you are giving me a way to check if the output of roomList[roomNameTest] is an IEnumerable but the error already told me the output is not, which despite giving me a way to detect it using code, it doesn't resolve the issue.